# Display following 2 elements on button click

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a ul li list.

On page load I want to hide all elements with class **hide** and on add more button i want to display next 2 elements and so on.

```js
$(function() {
  $('.hide').hide();

  $('#add_more').on('click', function() {
    // show
  })
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<button id="add_more">Add next 2</button>
<ul>
  <li class="show">1</li>
  <li class="show">2</li>
  <li class="hide">3</li>
  <li class="hide">4</li>
  <li class="hide">5</li>
  <li class="hide">6</li>
  <!-- Other elements -->
  <li class="hide">n</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: why do you hidding these li 's ,dont you add it dynamically?

Comment: @Sreeraj_ms I have some predefined static data

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To achieve this you can retrieve the last currently shown elements, then use `slice()` to get the following two and display them. Try this:

```js
$(function() {
  $('#add_more').on('click', function() {
    $('.show:last').nextAll().slice(0, 2).toggleClass('show hide');
  })
})
```

```css
.hide { display: none; }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<button id="add_more">Add next 2</button>
<ul>
  <li class="show">1</li>
  <li class="show">2</li>
  <li class="hide">3</li>
  <li class="hide">4</li>
  <li class="hide">5</li>
  <li class="hide">6</li>
  <!-- Other elements -->
  <li class="hide">n</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: this works but the previous result is not displaying

Comment: Not sure what you mean by 'previous result'

Comment: it should not toggle. it should just add. like 1, 2 and then 1,2,3,4

Comment: Ah, I see. In that case just remove the first `toggleClass()` call. I've updated the answer for you